# What is this Visual Studio plugin/option?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've been watching some videos on C# and the instructor has some type of plugin or option set that allows him to do some really neat things.

Here's an screenshot of what's going on. 
[image]

Basically, it's like a more advanced autocomplete or intellisense. Additionally, another feature I saw it do is if he clicks on the icon circled, he can change classes to public with just a click.

I know I sound very new to this, because I am (VS rookie). If anyone knows what amazing witchcraft this is, I'd love to know.

Thanks!

Comment: The one on the right is built in to VS since 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [code rush](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) and/or [refactor pro](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/refactor_pro.xml) by [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com).

The other big player in this arena is [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) by JetBrains.

Both are commercial add-ins to Visual Studio, though many of the refactoring and code generation helpers are built into Visual Studio (like the "implement abstract class" in your screen shot).